# Using fgets to get a line in C

Tags: c, string, fgets

I have this functions , but my fgets function doesn't work properly,can anyone help me ?
At case 3 , I ask the user to enter something he wants to search for the hotel, like a partial word, two words etc. po when i run it it doesn't work right , I dont understand why.

```
        scanf("%d", &option);


        case 3:
            printf("\nEnter the name of the hotel you want to search for.\n\n>>>");
            fgets(asked_hotel, sizeof(asked_hotel)-1, stdin);

            printf("The hotels matching what you searched are:\n\n");
            find_hotel(hotel_name,hotel_rating,address_name,city_name,address_code,NUM_HOTELS,asked_hotel);
```

Comment: What result do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Also, it's most probably not a problem with the `fgets` function, but with your `find_hotel` function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg When I select case 3 (pres 3), it should prompt me to put the word i search for, but instead it goes and prints, all the hotel by it self.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Maybe , do you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: And in that function, after you find the hotel in the first loop, why not reuse that index? You don't need the second loop to find the hotel (including lower-casing again). And you only need to lower-case the search string *once*, not once per loop.

Comment: Can you use _GDB_ and step through `find_hotel` function ?

Comment: can paste that piece of code, the way you think should be ?

Comment: @VoidPointer I don't know what GDB is

Comment: Then it is really good time to know about it. Google "gdb tutorial" to get millions of doc about that. Top hit , http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: @user2512806 GDB is a debugger :) download it

Comment: @PHIfounder , Huh , didn't know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is your use of `scanf` to get the option. It extracts the number, but leaves the newline in the buffer. This means that when you next call `fgets` it will read that newline and you will get an empty line.

The easiest solution is to ask `scanf` to skip trailing whitespace, including newlines. This is done by adding a space after the format code:

```
scanf("%d ", &option);
/*       ^         */
/*       |         */
/* Note space here */
```

Comment: I did this and , it works better, but not good enought, now, when I pres 3 and hit enter, it takes me to new line, and lives it there, if I enter the name of the hotel I want to search it finds it, but, it prompts me before i want to prompt my user.

Comment: @user2512806 In the `find_hotel` you use `scanf` with `%s` as the format code, but as argument you have a single character, that leads to undefined behavior. And of course you have the same problem with training whitepsace described in my answer.

Comment: @user2512806 try using `getchar();` after fgets it should work :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am doing what are you saying adding a space after the `%d` or `%s`. But it is not working correctly .

Comment: @user2512806 First fix your redundant code (to streamline the next step), then use a debugger and step though the code line by line. I'm sure you will find the problem quite easily then. And no, don't ask me to do it. SO is not a debugger, you have to do some work for yourself. See this as a useful learning experience, and experiment with the debugger, it's the most useful tool any programmer can have.

Comment: Okay  I am trying to do it and learn it. Can you help me with a debugger at least

Answer (score 0):

Recommend changing all your `scanf()` calls to `fgets()` / `sscanf()` pairs.  Example:

```
scanf("%d", &option);
```

to

```
char buf[80];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
sscanf(buf, "%d", &option);
```